# How much would a universal pageant representing the elements of nature cost?

Tags: earth-like

In comparing institutions such as the Miss America and Miss Universe series, how much would it cost to produce an international beauty pageant/fashion show illustrating the contestant's support and endorsement of clean, renewable technologies to improve water, earth, air, etc.?

A possible naming convention would be "Women of Nature Pageant" or "Ms. Ambassador Contest", respectfully.

Comment: Note that these types of competitions tend to generate revenue that greatly offset if not completely negate the cost of performing them.  If they were for profit, then you can bet they generate a positive amount after all is said and done.  I could not even hazard a guess to how much money a Victoria Secret pageant brings in.

Answer (score 1):

"Respectfully" is pretty hard to maintain -- not impossible but slips easily given that you're inherently using the objectivism of women as base for advertising, however noble the goal. But, if you're working on such things, find out the cost to produce Miss America and double it ... 50 states, 92 natural elements. Roughly double, and in my experience, theater productions/live scripted events generally scale with size of cast more than any other factor. If you can't find Miss America cost directly, you might be able to find Mr. Trump somewhere bragging about how much he spent on Miss Universe event and scale from that.

Comment: I did some quick research and you almost called it on Mr Trump bragging, it was his financial disclosure form that did it.  The Miss Universe Contest is valued at between $5-25 million [source](http://www.businessinsider.com/donald-trump-sells-miss-universe-img-2015-9)